# PHP - Unable to get same number of </ul> as <ul>

Tags: php, html

I am unable to generate same number of `</ul>` as `<ul>` in the following code:

```
<?php
$array=array("item1","item2","item3");
for ($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++)
{
    if($i<count($array)-1)
    {
    echo '<li><span>'.$array[$i].'</span><ul>';
    }
    else
    {
    echo '<li><span>'.$array[$i].'</span>';
    }
}
for ($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++)
{
    echo '</ul></li>';
}
?>
```

The code is generating uneven number of `<li><ul>` and `</ul></li>`. Please tell me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a minor error. In your second for statement change `$i<count($array);` to `$i<count($array)-1;`.

So your final code will be:

```
<?php
$array=array("item1","item2","item3");
for ($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++)
{
    if($i<count($array)-1)
    {
    echo '<li><span>'.$array[$i].'</span><ul>';
    }
    else
    {
    echo '<li><span>'.$array[$i].'</span>';
    }
}
for ($i=0;$i<count($array)-1;$i++)
{
    echo '</ul></li>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

With `if($i<count($array)-1)` you check if $i is smaller than the length - 1.

That check isn't performed in the second loop. So the first one actually performs as many steps as the second one but only writes in all but the last iteration.

Comment: Actually, I was getting more `</li></ul>` than `<li><ul>`. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @CraziestHacker Yep, and that's what my answer explains. Your first loop  prints one less because you check for `count($array)-1` and doesn't output until the last iteration of the loop

Comment: Oh, yes I think thats the problem, anyways got it resolved with the help of other answer posted above.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$array=array("item1","item2","item3");
echo '<ul>';
for ($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++)
{    
    echo '<li><span>'.$array[$i].'</span></li>';
}
echo '</ul>;
```

Comment: This does not help me, 'cause I need nested `<ul>`. You are changing the whole logic of my code.